# Experimental techniques to measure protein-protein and protein-ligand structure and dynamics

Tags: mathematical-models, theoretical-biology, protein-binding, protein-folding

We would like to compare our simulation results with experimentation. When one wants to follow experimentally the dynamics (and possibly structure) of protein-protein or protein-ligand docking (involving both small and large conformational changes for the complex), which are the most useful hydrodynamic techniques? If not hydrodynamic, which others?

Comment: NMR would be a method to get structural and dynamics information, but that is not a quick and easy method. Are you looking for atomic-resolution data, or for simpler methods that only give you some global information on the shape and dynamic of the protein?

Comment: I am interested in both, atomic resolution data, and/or "coarse grain" model data